# Get approximate total hit count beyond track_total_hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that you [can control with `track_total_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits) until which ElasticSearch does exact counting of hits. After it reaches the limit, it just says that there is more than those hits, but does not provide any more precise but still approximate total hint count. I wonder, is there a way to still obtain more precise but still approximate total count, e.g., using HyperLogLog++ or something. There is support for this in [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html), but how does one get it simply for the count of all hits in search results? Use aggregation on `_id` field?

Answer (score 0):

> After it reaches the limit, it just says that there is more than those hits, but does not provide any more precise but still approximate total hint count.

It's not true: `track_total_hits: true` will always provide the exact number of hits

> When set to true the search response will always track the number of hits that match the query accurately (e.g. total.relation will always be equal to "eq" when track_total_hits is set to true).

Comment: You are right, but I meant if I set `track_total_hits` to a number. I do not want to set it to `true` because i do not want exact number, but more performant approximation, but still better approximation than "more than X".

Comment: I'm curious about your use case. Care to share more?!

Comment: Oh, I just want to show to the user how many hits are there. Like what Google says, "approximate 16 million results". Not "more than 10k results".

Comment: Did you try `track_total_hits: true` and the response time was not satisfying?

Comment: I got scared by "Generally the total hit count can’t be computed accurately without visiting all matches, which is costly for queries that match lots of documents." in documentation, so I wonder if there is some other way to obtain counts which would require less resources. Especially because I do not mind being just approximate and not exact. But no, I have not observed slowdown myself, if this is what you are asking. I am still developing so I am not yet running on full data.

Comment: You know this quote, right? `Premature optimization is the root of all evil` ([source](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)) :-)

Comment: I do. :-) But learning how to optimize is also how one can learn a lot. And maybe there is a simple switch I have missed in documentation and would be trivial to use that instead of `track_total_hits: true`. This is why I am asking.

Comment: If there was a way, I would have mentioned it by now ;-)